# is it possible to create card scanner app using iphone camera?

Tags: ios, design-patterns

Is it possible to create an app that can detect card like a debit card of users using pattern recognition or from photo album just like face detection works in order to detect the face, I’d like to know could we create an app which can detect user's debit card?

Comment: why down voted its just a curious question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would take a look at [card.io](https://www.card.io/)

Comment: @DenisKozhukhov I agree, there could be many reasons not to use an framework / library / sdk, license for instance.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on your team :)

but technically it's possible. even on video stream. I know one team doing similar things - they can detect any dollars banknote on videostream. But they worked in this technology for 5 years. So it's image recognitions with a lot of math - but it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

A debit card or credit card contains a Magnetic strip which contains encrypted info and AFAIK there is no way to read that data with only camera and pattern Recognition.. With camera You can only read the card number, Bank name using OCR or user name if it is printed on the card.. for reading the Magnetic strip data you need a card reader which will be a separate hardware.

Comment: I think @sandeepsaurabh asked about detection - is this a cc or not, but not to grab data from it. In most cases - data gathered from cc sides is enough to do "some" things.